# Styling broad lines with short dashes

Tags: qgis

I'm looking to style some lines in QGIS to look like the steps in OpenStreetMap's default style. Actually, I'm styling those same steps on my own machine.

[image: steps from OSM]

Basically, unless I'm missing something, I need to make a dashed line that is wide with very short dashes.

I've tried setting a custom dash pattern, but qgis doesn't seem to take values of less than 1 because the size of the dash doesn't shrink after that point. So I can get a custom dash pattern with a dash that is as short as it is wide, but no shorter. Is there a way past this, or some other way to style the lines to look like steps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check out this video [here](http://youtu.be/FKfVIY_uGkY) which is for creating railway. i think you can do your needs with waching it.

[image: railway]

Basically:

1. Double click for Style
2. in sympol properties choose Marker Line from Symbol Layer Type
3. change your marker to short line with size 2 and interval 1
4. that is all

Settings from qgis:

[image: marker]

Result:

[image: markers]

i hope it helps you...